# Move through rows of a table using arrows keys in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to select and highlight rows of a table using arrow keys. The table gets displayed after entering some input inside a search bar.

I am trying to focus on the first row of table after the down key is pressed and then keep shifting the focus to subsequent rows. How do I move back and forth between rows using arrow keys?

I have tried various solutions but unable to achieve it. Can anyone please help me with this?

```js
$('#searchbar').on('input keydown', function(e) {
  if ($('#searchbar').val().length >= 3) {
    $('.child-div').show();
  }

  if (e.which == 40) {
    $('.child-div tr:first').addClass('highlight_row');
  }
})
```

```css
.highlight_row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded rounded-pill" placeholder="Text input" id="searchbar">
  <table class="table child-div" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` to find which row is currently highlighted (or store this in a variable) then use

```
$('.child-div tbody tr').removeClass("highlight").eq(current_row+1).addClass("highlight")
```

Updated snippet

```js
$('#searchbar').on('input keydown', function(e) {
  if ($('#searchbar').val().length >= 0) {
    $('.child-div').show();
  }

  if (e.which == 40) {
    var rows = $('.child-div tbody tr');
    var current = rows.filter('.highlight_row').index();
    // loop back to the top
    //if (current >= rows.length - 1) current = -1;
    // stop at the bottom
    if (current >= rows.length - 1) return;
    
    rows.removeClass("highlight_row");
    rows.eq(current+1).addClass('highlight_row');
  }
})
```

```css
.highlight_row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded rounded-pill" placeholder="Text input" id="searchbar">
  <table class="table child-div" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

For completeness, to include up cursor, it's essentially the same but using `current-1` which similar checks.  In this case, I'd move it out to its own function for clarity - this also means you could add page-up / page-down keypresses by simply setting the direction to (eg +10 / -10)

```js
$('#searchbar').on('input keydown', function(e) {
  if ($('#searchbar').val().length >= 0) {
    $('.child-div').show();
  }

  if (e.which == 38) highlightRow(-1)
  if (e.which == 40) highlightRow(1)
})

function highlightRow(direction)
{
  var rows = $('.child-div tbody tr');
  var current = rows.filter('.highlight_row').index();
  var next = current + direction;
  
  // stop at the top
  if (direction<0 && next < 0) next = 0
  // stop at the bottom
  if (direction>0 && next >= rows.length) next = rows.length - 1;

  rows.removeClass("highlight_row");
  rows.eq(next).addClass('highlight_row');
}
```

```css
.highlight_row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded rounded-pill" placeholder="Text input" id="searchbar">
  <table class="table child-div" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1. check the selected row (i.e. the `tr` with the class `hightlight_row`)
2. if the user presses <kbd>↑</kbd> and the selected row is not the first, then assign the `hightlight_row` class to the previous row
3. if the user presses <kbd>↓</kbd> and the selected row is not the last, then assign the `hightlight_row` class to the next row

```js
$(function() {
  const UP = 38;
  const DOWN = 40;
  const ARROWS = [UP, DOWN];
  const HIGHLIGHT = 'highlight_row';
  $('#searchbar').on('input keydown', function(e) {
    let $table = $('.child-div');
    if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {
      $table.show();
    } else {
      $table.hide();
    }
    let key = e.which;
    if (ARROWS.includes(key)) {
      let selectedRow = -1;
      let $rows = $table.find('tr');
      $rows.each(function(i, row) {
        if ($(row).hasClass(HIGHLIGHT)) {
          selectedRow = i;
        }
      });
      if (key == UP && selectedRow > 0) {
        $rows.removeClass(HIGHLIGHT);
        $rows.eq(selectedRow - 1).addClass(HIGHLIGHT);
      } else if (key == DOWN && selectedRow < $rows.length - 1) {
        $rows.removeClass(HIGHLIGHT);
        $rows.eq(selectedRow + 1).addClass(HIGHLIGHT);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight_row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded rounded-pill" placeholder="Text input" id="searchbar">
  <table class="table child-div" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note to advise that `:eq` is to be deprecated in jquery 3.4 https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: @AlessioCantarella Thanks for the solution ! It works perfectly. Now I am trying to get the data inside second col (i.e. td:nth-child(2) ) on hitting enter after the row is selected. I added the below condition in the if and else blocks of arrow keys block - if (key == UP && selectedRow > 0) {
        $('.child-div tr').removeClass(HIGHLIGHT);
        $('.child-div tr:eq(' + (selectedRow - 1) + ')').addClass(HIGHLIGHT);
        if(e.which==13){
          console.log($('td:nthchild(2)',this));
        } , but this doesn't give any value. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @ItykaBandta you should create another question 

Comment: If you added the `if key==13` code *inside* the `if key==up` code then there's your problem - it won't be both up and enter.   Put it at the same level as key=up.   But yes, up-vote *all* the helpful answers, pick one to mark as correct then ask a new question :)

Comment: @freedomn-m Hi. I have already upvoted your answer. I don't have enough reputation to reflect it. Please check my new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497381/fetch-data-of-highlighted-row-inside-a-table-on-hitting-enter-key , Would really appreciate if you could help.

Comment: @AlessioCantarella https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497381/fetch-data-of-highlighted-row-inside-a-table-on-hitting-enter-key Can you please answer this as well? I am a little stuck.

Answer (score 1):

#### It's another way to click and up/down arrow both change the highlighted row

```js
$('#searchbar').on('input keydown', function(e) {
  if ($('#searchbar').val().length >= 3) {
    $('.child-div').show();
  }
})

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {

  if($('.highlight_row')){
  
    var eqItem = $('.highlight_row').index(); 
  
    // key up
    if (e.which == 38) {
         if(eqItem==0) {return 0;}
             $('.table tbody tr').removeClass('highlight_row');
       $('.table tbody tr:eq('+(eqItem-1)+')').addClass('highlight_row');
    }
    // key down
    if (e.which == 40) {
        if(eqItem==$('.table tbody tr').length-1) {return 0;}
        $('.table tbody tr').removeClass('highlight_row');
        $('.table tbody tr:eq('+(eqItem+1)+')').addClass('highlight_row');
    }
  }
  
})

// click row heightlight change
$(document).on('click', '.table tbody tr',function(e){  
    $('.table tbody tr').removeClass('highlight_row');
    $(this).addClass('highlight_row');
})
```

```css
.highlight_row tr td,
.highlight_row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded rounded-pill" placeholder="Text input" id="searchbar">
  <table class="table child-div" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: also, you see this code here https://jsfiddle.net/yxsL68tv/

Comment: Thankss . This is a simpler alternative.

Comment: You are welcome @ItykaBandta. and also it helps you when multiple/more row in a table.