# Fetch data of highlighted row inside a table on hitting enter key

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a table that gets appended on entering some input inside a search box. I am navigating through the rows by using arrow keys. I want that when I hit the enter key , I get the data inside that selected/highlighted row.

For example, in the below code I want to I want to get the name of inside the td i.e. John, Jacob etc.

```js
            $(function() {
          const UP = 38;
          const DOWN = 40;
          const ARROWS = [UP, DOWN];
          const HIGHLIGHT = 'highlight_row';
          $('#searchbar').on('input keydown', function(e) {
            let $table = $('.child-div');
            if ($(this).val().length >= 3) {
              $table.show();
            } else {
              $table.hide();
            }
            let key = e.which;
            if (ARROWS.includes(key)) {
              let selectedRow = -1;
              let $rows = $table.find('tr');
              $rows.each(function(i, row) {
                if ($(row).hasClass(HIGHLIGHT)) {
                  selectedRow = i;
                }
              });
              if (key == UP && selectedRow > 0) {
                $rows.removeClass(HIGHLIGHT);
                $rows.eq(selectedRow - 1).addClass(HIGHLIGHT);
                
              } else if (key == DOWN && selectedRow < $rows.length - 1) {
                $rows.removeClass(HIGHLIGHT);
                $rows.eq(selectedRow + 1).addClass(HIGHLIGHT);
              }
            }
          });
        });
```

```css
            .highlight_row {
              background-color: red;
            }
```

```html
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <div class="container">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded rounded-pill" placeholder="Text input" id="searchbar">
              <table class="table child-div" style="display: none;">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
```

How to achieve this scenario ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code you're already working with, you can add

```
if (key == 13 && selectedRow > 0)
    name = $rows.eq(selectedRow).find(">td").eq(0).text()
```

By using `.find(">td")` you're finding only the `td` cells and your first column is a `th` so it skips that - meaning `0` is the first td

Because of the way the original code is written to get the selectedRow, I've included `13` in the `arrows` array so it goes in the same if (this is slightly confusing as it's not an arrow, but didn't want to change how it gets selectedRow too much as this is the solution you chose in your earlier question)

You could instead put the enter key check outside the arrow key array and use

```
$table.find('tbody tr.highlight_row > td').eq(0).text())
```

(see second snippet)

```js
$(function() {
  const UP = 38;
  const DOWN = 40;
  const ARROWS = [UP, DOWN, 13];
  const HIGHLIGHT = 'highlight_row';
  $('#searchbar').on('input keydown', function(e) {
    let $table = $('.child-div');
    $table.toggle($(this).val().length >= 1);

    let key = e.which;
    if (ARROWS.includes(key)) {
      let selectedRow = -1;
      let $rows = $table.find('tbody tr');
      $rows.each(function(i, row) {
        if ($(row).hasClass(HIGHLIGHT)) {
          selectedRow = i;
        }
      });
      if (key == UP && selectedRow > 0) {
        $rows.removeClass(HIGHLIGHT);
        $rows.eq(selectedRow - 1).addClass(HIGHLIGHT);

      } else if (key == DOWN && selectedRow < $rows.length - 1) {
        $rows.removeClass(HIGHLIGHT);
        $rows.eq(selectedRow + 1).addClass(HIGHLIGHT);
        
      } else if (key == 13 && selectedRow > 0) {
        alert($rows.eq(selectedRow).find(">td").eq(0).text())
        
      }
    }
    
    
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight_row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded rounded-pill" placeholder="Text input" id="searchbar">
  <table class="table child-div" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  const UP = 38;
  const DOWN = 40;
  const ARROWS = [UP, DOWN];
  const HIGHLIGHT = 'highlight_row';
  $('#searchbar').on('input keydown', function(e) {
    let $table = $('.child-div');
    $table.toggle($(this).val().length >= 1);

    let key = e.which;
    if (ARROWS.includes(key)) {
      let selectedRow = -1;
      let $rows = $table.find('tbody tr');
      $rows.each(function(i, row) {
        if ($(row).hasClass(HIGHLIGHT)) {
          selectedRow = i;
        }
      });
      if (key == UP && selectedRow > 0) {
        $rows.removeClass(HIGHLIGHT);
        $rows.eq(selectedRow - 1).addClass(HIGHLIGHT);

      } else if (key == DOWN && selectedRow < $rows.length - 1) {
        $rows.removeClass(HIGHLIGHT);
        $rows.eq(selectedRow + 1).addClass(HIGHLIGHT);
        
      } 
    }
    
    if (key == 13) {
        var row = $table.find('tbody tr.highlight_row')
        alert(row.find(">td").eq(0).text())
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight_row {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded rounded-pill" placeholder="Text input" id="searchbar">
  <table class="table child-div" style="display: none;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```